# Java War file deployment with a bunch of npm packages

Tags: java, node.js, npm, war

I'm working with a dynamic web project in Eclipse and I'm planning on a Java JAX-RS RESTful back-end with a JavaScript single-page app front-end using a framework of the Angular/Durandal/Aurelia flavor. With that said, the typical way to deploy in the Java world is to bundle things up as a WAR file - which is essentially a JAR file. The trouble is, including the node_modules blows up the size of the WAR file considerably. On the other hand, I can execute 'npm install' after deployment. However, on my development machine, where I'm constantly deploying, that will take too much time. I would prefer if I can prepare the install directory on the web server with the 'npm install' modules and then deploy the WAR file on top of it. The trouble is, it seems the WAR file deployment enjoys wiping out folders if they are not contained in the WAR file.

I'm using GlassFish 4.1 application server. The ideal solution for me would be a way to 'cloak' directory in the WAR file by modifying the MANIFEST.MF file such that when it is expanded the cloaked directories are not overwritten. This would be the most parsimonious solution to my problem. However, I know of no cloaking manifest entries for JAR/WAR file manifest.

There may also be creative solutions arrived at using the 'npm link' command. Any suggestions are welcome.

Perhaps this, among other reasons, speaks to why once people gets started with npm on the client-side they start looking at node and express on the server-side. However, I'm not convinced they can't play nice together and I would like to keep the option of all the old school open source Java libraries at my disposal.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is almost two years old, but perhaps someone will still need an answer.

Put simply, you need to bundle your JavaScript. You should *never* be wrapping up your node_modules folder in a war, or even deploying it as-is to the server. Mainly because of exactly the issue you were having. It's... not the smallest.

In front-end development, you're expected to use a tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to gather up all your JS files into a single app.js file. This process will only take the actual files you directly `require` or `import` in your own JavaScript (and the files that those files `require`, etc), leaving out all the rest. Most importantly for this discussion, leaving out all your `devDependencies`!

Webpack will also bundle up files other than js. Importing your css files will tell webpack to also bundle *those* up, creating an app.css file alongside your app.js (though you will need to use an appropriate [loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/) to tell Webpack what it *means* to `import 'main.css'`).

Getting started is a fairly straightforward matter of adding a config file to your project, adding a new devDependency, and figuring out how to get your Java-based build tool to trigger the bundler. The [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin), for instance, or the [gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin).

---

These days, webpack and its ilk are even smarter. If your node_modules contains ES6 native modules, bundlers can perform [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx) on these files to only bundle the exports that are actually imported. This reduces the bundle size even more.

They can also pull out parts of the bundle into a separate file in order to create, say, a vendor.js file that contains the code for Angular, jQuery, etc. Or you can tell the bundler to treat those imports as external, meaning that they are assumed to have been included elsewhere in the web app. But this is all getting into more advanced features than you need at first. Just give webpack's [getting started](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) guide a go, see the difference it immediately makes to your war size, and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you are using a nodejs build tool like Grunt (but probably not), then it's likely the devDependencies that's taking up so much space. If so, just copy your runtime dependencies out of node_modules.

If not: you don't *have* to deploy a .war; you can also deploy an 'exploded' directory. You could copy only changed files and [`touch .reload`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/gilfm.html#fwakh)

Comment: I'll give this a try. Part of problem is I'm migrating from Windows to Linux at the same time. .NET to Java, ASP.NET to Aurelia, Web API to JAX-RS. Fun. Seems like I can learn to write a small bash script that can manually copy some files and touch .reload and somehow hook that into an Eclipse deploy. Reasonable I'm guessing?

Comment: Yes, that'd be the fastest (`cp -ur target/webapp /path/to/applications/yourapp && touch /path/to/applications/.reload`). If you using any build tool besides Eclipse, say, Maven or Ant, then there's options there. You could also use a nodejs Grunt to copy files; whichever language you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Plus to mentioned above tools to pack NPM resources, let me also mention JNPM: https://github.com/OrienteerBAP/JNPM
It provides maven plugin (jnpm-maven-plugin) to download, filter and pack required NPM packages into your JAR/WAR. So in you case you should publish your client code as NPM package and then pack it into your WAR through this plugin.